# Issues related to navfn and global_planner plugin

Tags: ros, navfn, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ROS fuerte. I have gone through the [navfn](http://wiki.ros.org/navfn) .
I want a ROS plugin for my own global planner [I have Visited this page](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS).

I have following doubts:

- I want to my own global path planner to make two/three of different plans. All these plans will require to remove the inbuilt [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)  algorithm, implemented inside **navfn.cpp** and **used inside navfn_ros.cpp.** Will a single plugin serve my purpose or I have to make different plugins and make them switchable to decide the proper plan?
- Why two makePlan() methods are used (see [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/navfn/html/classnavfn_1_1NavfnROS.html))?
- In the link (http://www.iroboapp.org/index.php?title=Adding_Genetic_Algorithm_Global_Path_Planner_As_Plugin_in_ROS); they have not told anything about modification about **navfn.cpp.** .
- Finally, where the should I place the code specific to this plugin? Should I create a ***separate library*** containing all the files similar to **navfn**?

---

**Updated** based on Comment

### As mentioned in the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib), pluginlib is a C++ library for loading and unloading plugins from within a ROS package. Plugins are dynamically loadable classes that are loaded from a runtime library. So, in the
[tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS), a static makePlan() method is used. I observe that the Dijkstra's algorithm has to be modified and it is defined as calcNavFnDijkstra(true). Again, calcNavFnDijkstra(true) is defined inside navfn.cpp.  So, I want to know, if I write my own navfn.cpp which is the only source file in my plugin, can the other part of navfn_ros.cpp (defined inside navfn package) can relate to the new navfn.cpp dynamically?

I hope somebody has enough insight into the code to help me with these doubts.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201712/issues-related-to-navfn-and-global_planner-plugin/) by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2015-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to my own global path planner to make two/three of different plans. All these plans will require to remove the inbuilt Dijkstra's algorithm, implemented inside navfn.cpp and used inside navfn_ros.cpp. Will a single plugin serve my purpose or I have to make different plugins and make them switchable to decide the proper plan?

The [global planner interface](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/nav_core/include/nav_core/base_global_planner.h#L57) is defined so that you only return one plan. In order to use the navigation frame work as is, a global planner can only return one plan. That said, you could make several plans and then only return the best one.

> Why two makePlan() methods are used (see here)?

The one with the tolerance parameter allows for a plan that does not find the exact goal position, but instead has some tolerance.

> In the link ( http://www.iroboapp.org/index.php?tit... ); they have not told anything about modification about navfn.cpp. .

I'm not familiar with that tutorial.

> Finally, where the should I place the code specific to this plugin? Should I create a separate library containing all the files similar to navfn?

Yes.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-26**:
Thank you @David

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-26**:
If this is satisfactory, please click the check mark to mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-27**:
I have a doubt related to your last answer. In tutorial, only global_planner.cpp is used specific to plugin. **global_planner.cpp** is similar to **navfn_ros.cpp**. **calcNavFnDijkstra(true)** is used inside makePlan() method and computePotential() uses calcNavFnDijkstra(). calcNavFnDijkstra(true) is 2b changed

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-01-27**:
I'm really not sure what you're asking. If you're writing a new planner, you should make a new package. If you're modifying files from navfn, you should copy them over. If you're not modifying files from navfn, you should dynamically link to them.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-01-27**:
Sorry for not explaining my doubt @David. I have updated the question to incorporate the doubt.